# Help : ASP.NET MVC Unicode Route segments are wrongly ordered

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, routes

i have a very weird problem, let us suppose i have the following route

```
  context.MapRoute("ImageGallery_Default", "Image-Galleries/{category}", new { controller   = "Site", action = "Images", category = UrlParameter.Optional });
```

now if category route value is in English and for example has the value nature, the route will look fine like this

```
http://www.mysite.com/Image-Galleries/Nature
```

but if category route value has a Unicode Characters Arabic or Hebrew, the route gets messed up and category route value become before Image-Galleries like this

```
http://www.mysite.com/طبيعة/Image-Galleries
```

**Update 1**

seems that if the route has only one dynamic route value then it is not and issue, but more than that, the problem starts to be obvious, try this

```
public class FrontEndAreaRegistration : AreaRegistration
{
    public override string AreaName
    {
        get { return "FrontEnd"; }
    }

    public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context)
    {
 context.MapRoute("ImageGallery_Item", "Image-Galleries/{category}/{item}", new {     controller = "Site", action = "ImagesItem" });
    }
}
```

and here is my HTML

```
<a  href="@Url.RouteUrl("ImageGallery_Item", new { category = "طبيعة", item = "اوروبا", id = @item.Id })">اوروبا</a>
```

and here is how the link looks like in browser

```
http://www.mysite.com/Image-Galleries/طبيعة/اوروبا?id=16
```

notice how item routevalue is coming before hte category which should be hte ohter way around.

also there are no routes defined in Global.asax except

```
     public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.ashx/{*pathInfo}");
    }
```

i am all lost on this, i totally appreciate all help

Comment: Where does that string come from?

Comment: from   "HTML.RouteLink("ImageGallery_Default", new{category= @Model.Category}) which i get from DB

Answer (score 0):

You haven't provided enough context to allow us reproduce the problem. Here's what I tried and which worked as expected:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

    routes.MapRoute(
        "ImageGallery_Default", 
        "Image-Galleries/{category}", 
        new { controller = "Site", action = "Images", category = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );

    routes.MapRoute(
        "Default",
        "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );
}
```

and in the view:

```
@Html.RouteLink("ASCII link", "ImageGallery_Default", new { category = "nature" }) 
<br/>
@Html.RouteLink("Unicode link", "ImageGallery_Default", new { category = "طبيعة" })
```

and here's how the resulting HTML page looks like:

```
<a href="/Image-Galleries/nature">ASCII link</a> 
<br/>
<a href="/Image-Galleries/%D8%B7%D8%A8%D9%8A%D8%B9%D8%A9">Unicode link</a>
```

which is exactly what we might expect.

Comment: thank you Darin,i have updated my question to reflect the problem better  please do tell me what more context you want me to provide ?

Comment: @DevMania, as I did in my question: provide your full route definition, provide a simple snippet from your view (with hardcoded values), talk about the areas, ... Something that allows to reproduce the problem.

Comment: DevMartin, i have updated my question again, if you could please take look at it